# Get Html.ActionLink parameters from li element with query

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html-lists, actionlink

I have this unordered list:

```
     <ul class="list"> 
         <li class="navItem">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
         <li class="navItem">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "ContactForm", "Contact")</li>
     </ul>
```

and in my script i want to select the li element by his action and controller name, that i can retrieve data like width and position from the specific li element.

my Function looks like this, but i don't know how the selector has to look like.

```
    function currentItem() {

     //Here i get the current view and controller name
     var actionName = '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString()';
     var controllerName = '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString()';
     // something like that, putting the link together?
     var $currentItem = $('a[href="' + viewController + controllerName + '"]'); 

     // or find all elements by class name an than do something like
     var myArray = $('.navItem');

     if (myArray[0].Controller == controllerName ||myArray[0].Action == actionName)  {
     $currentItem = myArray[0];
     }

      return $currentItem;
      }
```

Thanks for helping.

Franhu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all lets consider what HTML we will be working with. A `Html.ActionLink` will convert into an `a` tag, so your HTML will look something like this:

```
<li class="navItem"><a href="/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
```

With that in mind we can iterate the `li` elements, check their inner `a` element and match on the `href` attribute.

So something like this should work:

```
function currentItem() {
    var actionName = '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString()';
    var controllerName = '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString()';

    var listItems = $('.navItem');

    for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++){
        var item = $(listItems[i]);
        var a = item.find("a");
        if(a.attr["href"].indexOf(controllerName + "/" + actionName) != -1){
            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this will return the matching `li` element. If you want the matching `a` element then use `return a;` instead.

Comment: Good solution, i tried it but the problem is the href attribute has not every time the same structure. for the first li elements with home and index the href is only "/" and for the contact "/Contact/ContactForm". Is there to do this? ty

Comment: In the instance of your Home/Index, what are the values returned for controllerName and actionName?

Comment: ControllerName: Home, actionName:Index. Is there a way to get the full path of the action link, something like: @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", FullPath-Parameter)?